Change user UID and GID to 1000:1000 in Ubuntu
While my user has UID:GID 1000:1000 in my laptop (Pop! OS), a new desktop machine (Ubuntu 22.04.4) got the same user name with UID:GID 1001:1001 by default. This creates permission problems when working with an external disk that is frequently connected to either machine. According to what I have read (eg https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-user-group-uid-gid-for-all-owned-files/), changing UID:GID in the desktop (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) machine is easily done with
usermod -u 1000 foo
groupmod -g 1000 foo

My concern is: is 1000:1000 reserved in Ubuntu? Might I be creating a trouble using these UID:GID numbers?

You can check if uid/gid 1000 is in use with this command. If it's not in use, it's safe to change. My uid/gid has been 1000 for over a decade and I haven't had any issue.
grep 1000 /etc/passwd /etc/group


Had to login as root, as the change cannot be done from the same user. While new files can be created to the desktop disk with the 1000:1000 UID and GID, the external drive can be mounted but cannot be accessed: "This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view th contents of "SP PHD U3".
